# Different Keyboards equals different backlights?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, repair

i replaced my old keyboard (german layout) with an us keyboard. It works fine but the backlight seems to be misfit a litte. Is it possible that they using different kinds of backlights?

Comment: Misfit how, please describe how it is being different?

Comment: i dont really know if it is different but i think so, because the backlight is irregular.

Comment: I don't believe the backlighting differs on a per language basis. May be it's different manufacturing process because the US keyboard is newer than the German one?

Comment: Which MacBook / MacBook Pro do you have?

Comment: i own the MacBook Pro 15" early 2011